# How to target input element whose id, class and xpath changing with every refresh. webdriver Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```html
<div class="label-txt">User Name</div> 
    <input name="xugw1irortn1ogkpy31wxl" type="text" id="xugw1irortn1ogkpy31wxl" style="display:none;" />
    <input name="bzzunemwbpxl44jnmxr0bt" type="text" id="bzzunemwbpxl44jnmxr0bt" style="display:none;" />
    <input name="w4gxjqkwvd4pqp4xrevu2r" type="text" id="w4gxjqkwvd4pqp4xrevu2r" style="display:none;" />
    <input name="bzxdws3vj041exduu1125j" type="text" id="bzxdws3vj041exduu1125j" style="display:none;" />
    <input name="lun5ji01ou4wpyvzaypji1" type="text" id="lun5ji01ou4wpyvzaypji1" style="display:none;" />
    <input name="x1rkfxp4sjwojbvr2uptuz" type="text" id="x1rkfxp4sjwojbvr2uptuz" style="display:none;" />
    <input name="cptv2l0ffvzpwqk0wetlnh" type="text" id="cptv2l0ffvzpwqk0wetlnh" style="display:none;" />
    <input name="couyswy1yfm51bpnyzkyrg" type="text" id="couyswy1yfm51bpnyzkyrg" style="display:none;" />
    <input name="yninikw54iudxqqlzgmxir" type="text" id="yninikw54iudxqqlzgmxir" style="display:none;" />
    <input name="ngb4uczri1l5ftyqvppbgk" type="text" id="ngb4uczri1l5ftyqvppbgk" style="display:none;" />
    <input name="e5dt2tozqrbrqxsivl0ygk" type="text" id="e5dt2tozqrbrqxsivl0ygk" style="display:none;" />
    <input name="rkcjmknvghdly0vk03ynmf" type="text" id="rkcjmknvghdly0vk03ynmf" style="display:none;" />
    <input name="moostndi5vtvpc0fy5sboa" type="text" id="moostndi5vtvpc0fy5sboa" style="display:none;" />
    <input name="1bps10gceliasg41iy455l" type="text" id="1bps10gceliasg41iy455l" style="display:none;" />
    <input name="a1z1amtyvnrtad55ywiqnc" type="text" id="a1z1amtyvnrtad55ywiqnc" style="display:none;" />
    <input name="m3jyv1ibdslgoelr5wdlfd" type="text" id="m3jyv1ibdslgoelr5wdlfd" style="display:none;" />
    <input name="4dgqbpwew3ngbgwdnxaqf4" type="text" id="4dgqbpwew3ngbgwdnxaqf4" style="display:none;" />
    <input name="hocvr1ykprqs5a4agnnfie" type="text" id="hocvr1ykprqs5a4agnnfie" />
    <span id="ctl03" style="color:Red;visibility:hidden;">*</span>
</div>

<div class="label-txt">Password</div> 

 <input name="xugw1irortnb5sraht3azj" type="password" id="xugw1irortnb5sraht3azj" style="display:none;" />
 <input name="bzzunemwbpxb1vpydi1qcv" type="password" id="bzzunemwbpxb1vpydi1qcv" style="display:none;" />
 <input name="w4gxjqkwvd4n50vqqehcab" type="password" id="w4gxjqkwvd4n50vqqehcab" style="display:none;" />
 <input name="bzxdws3vj04w2iargab32a" type="password" id="bzxdws3vj04w2iargab32a" style="display:none;" />
 <input name="lun5ji01ou42tafgvmhc4t" type="password" id="lun5ji01ou42tafgvmhc4t" style="display:none;" />
 <input name="x1rkfxp4sjwtlwvdpsdjkq" type="password" id="x1rkfxp4sjwtlwvdpsdjkq" style="display:none;" />
 <input name="cptv2l0ffvznmop4iqycoe" type="password" id="cptv2l0ffvznmop4iqycoe" style="display:none;" />
 <input name="couyswy1yfm22nbvshuvrv" type="password" id="couyswy1yfm22nbvshuvrv" style="display:none;" />
 <input name="yninikw54iub5zucjoseb2" type="password" id="yninikw54iub5zucjoseb2" style="display:none;" />
 <input name="ngb4uczri1lmusbh0ztgkf" type="password" id="ngb4uczri1lmusbh0ztgkf" style="display:none;" />
 <input name="e5dt2tozqrbiseaipzetp1" type="password" id="e5dt2tozqrbiseaipzetp1" style="display:none;" />
 <input name="rkcjmknvghdfdmhcpfhvrv" type="password" id="rkcjmknvghdfdmhcpfhvrv" style="display:none;" />
 <input name="moostndi5vtep5rwqi5llx" type="password" id="moostndi5vtep5rwqi5llx" style="display:none;" />
 <input name="1bps10gceliy02zzdkpx5p" type="password" id="1bps10gceliy02zzdkpx5p" style="display:none;" />
 <input name="a1z1amtyvnrdygk03jr3vf" type="password" id="a1z1amtyvnrdygk03jr3vf" style="display:none;" />
 <input name="m3jyv1ibdslxju0pbgrmbn" type="password" id="m3jyv1ibdslxju0pbgrmbn" style="display:none;" />
 <input name="4dgqbpwew3n5ru3dbxnzxo" type="password" id="4dgqbpwew3n5ru3dbxnzxo" style="display:none;" />
 <input name="hocvr1ykprqlzaevxie2iv" type="password" id="hocvr1ykprqlzaevxie2iv" />
 <span id="ctl04" style="color:Red;visibility:hidden;">*</span>
</div>
```

I am trying to login into a  .aspx website using selenium Python webdriver but the problem is the `id` `class` and `xpath` are changing with reload or refresh. Even, there is multiple `input`  for user and password entry.

[**source code screenshot:**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6FJi.png)
[**UI screenshot:**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NA66S.png)

Comment: @JainishKapadia , `HTML`  code added

Comment: @TheBlueMagician, share also code (selectors) you've tried already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use below `XPath` expressions:

```
//div[text()="User Name"]/following-sibling::input[not(@style="display:none;")]
```

for `Username` field and

```
//div[text()="Password"]/following-sibling::input[not(@style="display:none;")]
```

for `Password`

Comment: @Anderson your `xpath` for `user name` locate the both elements.

Comment: Yes. It should return 2 elements. But with `find_element_by_xpath(XPATH)` first one will be found - the required one. OP can use `find_elements_by_xpath(XPATH)[0]`, but I see no reason for these

Comment: So, i guess we should use here `indexing` after end of the `xpath` like this `//div[text()='User Name']/following-sibling::input[not(@style="display:none;")][1]`

Comment: No. In case we need to use `Password` `input` field with the same `XPath`, then it is OK to use index, but in this case there is no need as required element is already the first one to be found